# Testing case where null should be returned using RestController with Mockito Fails

Tags: java, spring, jpa, testing, mockito

I want to test for a NullPointerException case that should be thrown by the controller that I am testing, but I always get NullPointerException error. I am trying to test the case where a user with a certain id is not found in the db. Is my way of doing that a valid way? If not, then how should I test that case? I haven't found any valuable info about this certain test case.

My Controller Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest
{
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
public void testGetUserById_Status200_EmptyJsonPath() throws Exception
{
   when(userRepository.findById(999)).thenReturn(null);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/user/{user_id}", 999))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

    verify(userRepository, times(1)).findById(999);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(userRepository);
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController
{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{user_id}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable int user_id) throws Exception
{
    return userRepository.findById(user_id).orElse(null);
}
}
```

Error I get:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at spring.controller.UserControllerTest.testGetUserById_Status200_EmptyJsonPath(UserControllerTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:365)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spring.controller.UserController.getUser(UserController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Why should it be different? Throwing an exception is not covered in your controller. On a related note your test is flawed. Remove the `setUp` method and place `@Autowired` on `MockMvc`. Spring Boot does al of this for you already and you are doing it again (basically duplicating the test setup and memory usage).

Comment: It seems there is no exception handler to your controller. So It will give 500 Internal Server Error as a result. So what would you expected that test ?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut I am trying to test the case where a user with a certain id is not found in the db. Is my way of doing that a valid way? If not, then how should I test that case? I haven't found any valuable info about this certain test case

Comment: When a user is not found the result will be an empty optional NOT a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response. You are right about that, I just didn't know what to return if a user was not found in db. I changed the test to the following code and it worked:         when(userRepository.findById(999)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/{userID}", 999))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$").doesNotExist());

        verify(userRepository, times(1)).findById(999);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(userRepository);
Is there more to it or is this enough to test tht user wasn't found in db?

Comment: Depends on what you expect and what you think should happen. I doubt it will pass and result in a 404 without some handing of the empty case. You are returning `null` so unless you have some generic way of converting that into a 404 I doubt it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
assertThatNullPointerException().isThrownBy(() -> userRepository.findById(999));
```

make sure you import following to use this method

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatNullPointerException;
```